# Facebook Push Campaign with Banner Not working iOS 11

Tags: facebook, push-notification, ios11

I am using this Facebook Push Campaign, [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/push-notifications/ios) is the integration of Facebook Push Notifications. I use Swift 3.2 and iOS11, I wrote this line of code.

```
func application( _ application: UIApplication,didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    FBNotificationsManager.shared().presentPushCard(forRemoteNotificationPayload: userInfo, from: nil) { viewController, error in
          if let _ = error { 
            completionHandler(.failed)
        } else {
            completionHandler(.newData)
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error always

> Error Domain=FBNotificationsErrorDomain Code=1 "Invalid remote notification payload for presenting push card." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid remote notification payload for presenting push card.}

I am getting normal push notifications from Facebook but if it contains banner it fails and show me above error.

Comment: Hi. Any progress with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to send `In-App Notification` from Facebook Analytics. I was doing the same mistake: sending a normal Push Notification. As a side note, the function `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)` gets called twice when opening the app by tapping the notification. Be mindful of this